# Learndash extended quiz report

Tags: wordpress, learndash

Good day everyone!
I am having a problem with LearnDash quiz report feature. I found no way to find overall students question with their answers in somekind of xls/CSV document. I need a table, where will be students in one column and their answers on every question in other columns for selected quiz.

Does anybody found a solution/plugin for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Advanced > Import/Export

Or use the following URL path:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=learndash_lms_advanced&section-advanced=settings_import_export

Or if you are an advanced user and you can use a PHP database results object as per your requirements, so the following PHP function can be used from the following plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/toolkit-for-learndash-lms/

**tkflld_get_quiz_statistic**

P.S. answer_data is the user input.

Output:

```
[statistic_ref_id] => 9
[question_id] => 1
[correct_count] => 1
[incorrect_count] => 0
[hint_count] => 0
[points] => 1
[question_time] => 0
[answer_data] => [0,1,1,1]
[question_post_id] => 10360
[quiz_id] => 2
[user_id] => 1
[create_time] => 1662137665
[is_old] => 0
[form_data] => 
[quiz_post_id] => 10358
[course_post_id] => 10354
```